# Google cloud function deployment error in Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a google cloud function. But getiing error as I am not able to figure out how to deploy using vendor directory. My project directory follows:

```
Repo Name (github.com/org-name/repo-name)
 -internal
    -somepackage1
       -function1.go
    -somepackage2
       -function2.go
 -cloudfunction
    -func.go
```

Now I want to deploy this cloud function(func.go) on google cloud which uses some functions of function1.go and function2.go. So I am creating a go.mod file in cloudfunction directory So when I call go mod vendor, in vendor directory, structure looks like:

```
-cloudfunction
      -func.go
      -vendor
         -github.com
           -org-name
             -repo
                -internal
                  -somepackage1
                     -function1.go
                  -somepackage2
                     -function2.go
```

But as go doesn't allow internal package functions outside of parent directory(repo), I can't call them from func.go, what's the better way to handle this issue.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think changing the internal folder to the pkg or src folder could work. Since the code is being used in an external ‘thing’, having the code in the internal folder doesn’t make much sense, at least to me.

Comment: @ThijsvanderHeijden
Yes that's a way, but whenver the repo code got deployed the cloud functions are also deployed and if someone changes the repo code, we have to manually update the code in vendor directory as well and I want to avoid that.